# Java regex: extract function names

Tags: java, regex, capturing-group

I'm trying to extract a list of function names from a formula, but my regex is not working.

Given `( aaa(111) + bbb(222) ) / ccc ( 333 )` I need to obtain an array of strings containing `aaa`, `bbb` and `ccc`. Instead, I'm getting `aaa(`, `bbb(` and `ccc (`. how to make this work?

This is my attempt:

```
    String formula = "( aaa(111) + bbb(222) ) / ccc ( 333 )";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((\\w+)\\s*\\()");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(formula);

    while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you'll need a parser. You haven't specified the exact rules, but a regex generally isn't powerful enough to do this.

Comment: You should take group(2) from the match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got nested capture groups, make the first one a non-capture group:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:(\\w+)\\s*\\()");
```

or as pointed out by [Didier L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/525036/didier-l) just remove the outer group:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((\\w+)\\s*\\(");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 capturing groups in your pattern:

- the external parentheses
- the ones around `\\w+`

Since you are only interested in the second one, you should either

- take the second group: `matcher.group(2)`
- remove the external parentheses:

  ```
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s*\\(");
  ```

Notice that `matcher.group(0)` is always the match of the whole pattern (so equivalent to your external parentheses here)